# HTML columns not evenly spaced?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning HTML yesterday. I have some Python experience so this isn't too bad.
My question is that my columns aren't evenly spaced here and when I try to add a new section after this, it adds another line to the column.

```
<!DOCTYPE.html>
<html>
        <style>
            html {
                cursor: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732378808132436010/1005850390249607209/Untitled_40_40_px_2.png"), auto;
            }
        </style>
<body style="background-color:black;">
<p style="text-align:center;">
<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732623682576580719/1005689024817668116/Screen_Shot_2022-08-07_at_12.06.59_AM.png" alt="Music Feedback">
</p>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <style>
        .test{
            cursor:url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732378808132436010/1005851128421953596/Untitled_40_40_px_3.png"), auto
        }
    </style>

      <h2><a href="www.google.com" style="color:rgb(227, 131, 227)" class="test">Who We Are</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2><a href="www.google.com" style="color:rgb(227, 131, 227)" class="test">News & Events</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2><a href="www.google.com" style="color:rgb(227, 131, 227)" class="test">Contact</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I think my floats/paddings/etc are causing it? But I can't be sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You CSS definitions do not always have the closing bracket (`}`) so they are likely not applying correctly to your page (HTML) - fix those first and then [edit] your question with the correct [mre].  Also, you have multiple `<body>` tags (opening and closing) which is not valid HTML (only one body tag per page)

Comment: Thank you! I cleaned up what you said. However, it's still not evenly placed from left to right as a banner.

Comment: Hmmm, the question above continues to show the items I pointed out sooo... You can [edit] the question to add the changes.  Also I posted an answer below to see if it does the trick for you,

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Tweaking things on my end. Trying the code you sent--which is beautiful.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, up vote it and/or mark it as done.

Answer (score 0):

I removed styles from HTML (poor practice) and moved them into the CSS (better practice).

Cleaned up the HTML a bit and removed the `float` attribute (poor practice) for placement.

This might not be all you need but I think it can get you closer to what you asked for.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.row-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

html,
.header-img:hover {
  cursor: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732378808132436010/1005850390249607209/Untitled_40_40_px_2.png"), auto;
}

.column {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

.test:hover {
  cursor: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732378808132436010/1005851128421953596/Untitled_40_40_px_3.png"), auto;
}

a.test {
  color: rgb(227, 131, 227);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row row-header">
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732623682576580719/1005689024817668116/Screen_Shot_2022-08-07_at_12.06.59_AM.png" alt="Music Feedback" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2><a href="www.google.com" class="test">Who We Are</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2><a href="www.google.com" class="test">News & Events</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2><a href="www.google.com" class="test">Contact</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```